# using while in function for getting input, and it shows argument of type 'builtin_function_or_method' is not iterable

Tags: python, input, while-loop, function

I'm using this inside the function to get month and year input,

```
mon = ""

while mon not in 'januar februar mart april maj jun jul avgust septembar oktobar novembar decembar'.split:

    mon = input('Mesec: ')
    mon = mon.lower()
    yr = ""    
    print('Molim vas izaberite godinu. (npr. 2014)')

    while int(yr) not in range(2013,2050):

        yr = input()
```

and it's giving me next:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\Scan-inprogress.py", line 255, in <module>
    docMonthMoney(data)
  File "C:\Python33\Scan-inprogress.py", line 151, in docMonthMoney
    while mon not in 'januar februar mart april maj jun jul avgust septembar oktobar novembar decembar'.split:
TypeError: argument of type 'builtin_function_or_method' is not iterable
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Note that instead of `int(yr) not in range(2013, 2050)` I would write `not (2013 <= int(yr) < 2050)`. It's equivalent and doesn't build a whole list each time.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich: the OP is using Python 3.3, so it doesn't build the list each time.  (I'd still use the inequalities, though.)

Comment: @RemcoGerlich: nope, doesn't generate all the values.  `range` is now more like `xrange`; `range(2013, 2050)` produces a `range` object.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich: no, it doesn't.  Try `10**99 in range(1, 10**100)` or `10**101 in range(1, 10**100)` -- you get the result back instantly.  Please read the [range documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to *call* `split`:

```
while mon not in "...".split():
                          # ^ note parentheses
```

Otherwise, you are trying to iterate through (the `builtin_function_or_method`) `str.split`, rather than the list of strings calling it returns.

Comment: But when I get to year part it gets me this

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''